# Ehcache + Spring 4 + Weblogic 12c = ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, ehcache, classnotfoundexception

i think i browsed EVERYTHING on stackoverflow about this issue, but i can't solve it.
Assuming that:

- i tried 4.2.5, 4.2.6, 4.3.0 spring versions
- i tried 2.9.0 to the last 2.10.2.2.21 ehcache versions
- i have in my pom (and in the resulting war) spring-context, spring-context-support, ehcache jars
- i'm deploying an EAR containing a WAR including in its /WEB-INF/lib directory all required above jars
- my EAR is perfectly working on my 3 dev environments (eclipse + Weblogic 12c on Windows 7, OSX and Ubuntu)

when i try to deploy the same EAR on a test environment based on Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0 i encounter this damned stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
....
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:267)
at com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:62)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:291)
```

I also tried to package my EAR in a different way, building a skinny war and including all jars as EAR libraries, but it didn't work.
I have never experienced a classloading issue like this...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Weblogic not finding a class from a library because it was actually using another version of that library that was already in its classpath.

First, make sure it doesn't already have a different version of ehCache somewhere, if so, you can tell Weblogic to use the version embedded in your app for a specific package in your WebLogic deployment descriptor file (`WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`) :

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app ...>
    ...
    <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>net.sf.ehcache</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP663